# Host JSON on path AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to figure out how to do this, and I might be just missing something obvious. But we are need to host an [AASA - Apple App Site Association](https://branch.io/glossary/aasa-apple-app-site-association/) on our page.

But I do not know how to do this using AngularJS. It feels like this is an easy operation, and that is just strengthend by my inability to find information about this.

How would one serve a static JSON file using AngularJS, state and $stateProvider? Or am I approaching this issue the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an API call to that static JSON. First, please note the JSON has to be on an URL, even accessible when in local with `127.0.0.1/path_to_json` or `filename.json` if the js and json share parallel location in the server, and that hosting it in a drive and accessing it via `C:/path_to_json` wouldn't work.

Now, to make an API call and use $state to store data, do like this:

```
$state.data;
$http.get('url_to_json').success(function(data) {
// you can do some processing here
$state.data = data;
});
```

You can access data via `{data}` in your view.

Now since you want to serve this using `$stateProvider`, which is basically routing in angularJS, you can make this API call in service and the data will automatically be available through the application, no extra work needed!